# Can i use python script to add users (mac auth) to Freeradius 3.0?

Tags: python, freeradius

I've been searching for any examples using python script to add users to freeradius, but i guess i'm using wrong keywords. can i ask for your help regarding how to implement this? im still new with python and freeradius. thank you

**edited
im using Daloradius with Wifi hotspot

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes you can.

This is really more focussed on system administration at this stage so it may receive better answers on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), until you get into the specifics of the python side of things.

That said, the way I'd do it is use a database of MAC addresses, and update that database using python. As you can guess there are a lot of different ways to do this. Perhaps start from the bottom ("SQL" section) of this page: https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/mac-auth

Get database-based MAC auth working first, then consider how to script updates to the database.

Comment: thank you for sharing your answers, i will definitely look into it and will try to learn this things.